# When should we release an object if we are returning it?

Tags: ios, memory-management

Check the following method:

```
-(NSMutableArray*)provideRequestArray{
    NSMutableArray* requestArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"MyString",nil];
    return requestArray;
}
```

Now when should `requestArray` be released so it doesn't produce any consequences.

Comment: Why are you returning an array when your method name suggests that you get a string?

Comment: ah.. coz i have been dealing with the string, initially..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Return that object sending an `autorelease` message.

```
// initWithFormat: ??
NSMutableArray* requestArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]
                              initWithFormat:@"MyString"];
return [requestArray autorelease];
```

or get an autoreleased one (for instance with `array` class method) :

```
NSMutableArray* requestArray= [NSMutableArray array];
return requestArray;
```

Check out the doc [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: so what if I make the object auto reslease?

Comment: the autorelease object will be released later. So the sender might `retain` that object.

Comment: can we use `return [classObject autorelease];` too?

Comment: use `autorelease` only with object you own and you need to return to sender. if `classObject` is an autoreleased object you got back from message sending, there no need to use that.

Comment: Oh actually `classObject` is object of a class and it's not autoreleased.

Comment: so autorelease it before returning it.